# Не получается зайти в Ubuntu после установки Windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, grub, dual-boot

Извините сразу, если нельзя такие вопросы задавать. Такой вопрос. Изначально при покупки ноутбука у меня стоял **Ubuntu**. Поверх него я установил **Windows 10**. Теперь я не могу зайти в **Ubuntu**. Я пытался гуглить, единственное, что я смог найти это проблема в **grub**. Я пытался его установить, но все без результатно. Прогать нужно, помогите. На винде прогать это убого с их переменными средами.

Comment: Такие, может, и можно, только этот вопрос и до вас тыщу раз по всему интернету задавали :)

Comment: Проверте режим загрузчика, поменяйте с Legacy На UEFI Или наоборот, просто скорее всего загрузчике винды стоит первым, и приоритетным.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов в биосе?

Comment: @Санаев  да. (Нужно 5 символов).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin то что там написано не работает!

Comment: Можно скриншот из "управления дисками"? Ну или из любой проги, которая показывает инфу по разделам.

Comment: уважаемые те кто отметил, что это дубликат. посмотрите какие там даны ответы. версии разные. и исправление разное!!!